Amadeus soap request keeps giving me error about wrong headers
I am creating a Fare_TravelBoardSearch request for amadeus enterprise flight api. I have created a reqeuest in c# using amadeus's wsdl and when that didn't work i took the simpler option of creating one in soapui. both of them are giving similliar errors:
soap:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>12|Presentation|soap message header incorrect</faultstring>
         <faultactor>SI:muxDZ1</faultactor>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

c# exception:
{" 12|Presentation|soap message header incorrect"}

my c# code is as follows:
AmadeusWebServices.AmadeusWebServicesPTClient client = new AmadeusWebServices.AmadeusWebServicesPTClient("AmadeusWebServicesPort");
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
                AmadeusWebServices.Session session = new AmadeusWebServices.Session();
                AmadeusWebServices.AMA_SecurityHostedUser securityHostedUser = new AmadeusWebServices.AMA_SecurityHostedUser()
                {
                    UserID = new AmadeusWebServices.AMA_SecurityHostedUserUserID()
                    {
                        AgentDutyCode = "DC",
                        PseudoCityCode = "CityCode",
                        POS_Type = "1"
                    },
                    WorkstationID = "WorkstationId"
                };
                AmadeusWebServices.TransactionFlowLinkType transactionFlowLinkType = new AmadeusWebServices.TransactionFlowLinkType();
                AmadeusWebServices.Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch = new AmadeusWebServices.Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch();
                var result = client.Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch(ref session, ref transactionFlowLinkType, securityHostedUser, fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch);

                Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");

and here is my request from soapUI :
enter image description here

I suspect you are failing a schema check (xsd file).  Did you include all the namespaces in the example in you code?  You may be using an older version of one of the namespaces.  Copying old code may not work if the website was updated.
